# How to inject a TextMate grammar to a Markdown heading in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I want to select `[ ]` for syntax highlighting within a markdown file in VS Code.

I can target `[ ]` using the following `regex`: `(?<=\s)\]|\[(?=\s)`.
However `[ ]` doesn't get matched when it is part of a heading.

As a minimal example, in the `package.json` I have the following:

```json
"contributes": {
    "grammars": [
        {
            "scopeName": "markdown.todo",
            "path": "./syntaxes/todo.markdown.json",
            "injectTo": ["text.html.markdown"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in the `todo.markdown.json` I have:

```json
{
    "scopeName": "markdown.todo",
    "injectionSelector": "L:text.html.markdown",
    "patterns": [
        { "include": "#item-todo" }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "item-todo": {
            "name": "item.todo",
            "match": "(?<=\\s)\\]|\\[(?=\\s)"
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the VS Code `settings.json` I apply a color using:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "item.todo",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can see below that `[ ]` gets selected, but not when it is within a heading.

[image]

When I inspect the tokens and scopes I see several `textmate scopes`.
I am not sure if this is related, but it seems that VS Code is highlighting the markdown headings based on the `markup.heading` scope. However, `markup.heading` is not present in the `textmate scopes` array.

[image]

I tried changing to `"injectionSelector": "L:heading.1.markdown"` and/ or `"injectTo": ["heading.1.markdown"]`, but no matter what selectors I specify I cannot seem to be able to match `[ ]` within a heading.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me... (I am running it inside a yeoman vscode extension project built by the CLI tool)  (I have no other markdown plugins installed) have you tried installing this micro extension config into a fresh VS-Code installation? maybe some other config/installed thing is getting in the way